# Blackberry support for Forms Authentication - ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blackberry, forms-authentication

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Forms Authentication. The target clients are a variety of mobile web browsers.

When I use the BlackBerry 8530 simulator my MVC app authenticates as expected. I can visit pages whose controller methods are decorated with the [Authorize] attribute - no problem - they display and therefore I assume my Forms Authentication is working correctly.

Using a physical Windows Mobile device to browse my site, I have the same experience as the BB simulator, the forms authentication works as I would expect.

BUT when I try to visit the site using a Blackberry 8900 physical device the Login page keeps on looping back when I click the Login page. The device is not retaining it's "authenticated" status.

I added code to verify this and I can see that:
Request.IsAuthenticated: False
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated: False

So my question is what next steps can I take to try and find out why the Blackberry 8900 is losing it's authentication status. Is this cookie related?

Anyone have any ideas?

Cheers
Derek

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config, try to put `cookieless="true"` in the `sessionState` tag

Comment: Gregoire, when I add the cookieless="true" it breaks the URL rewriting.

Comment: @Derek Mitchell If you can not modify your URL route neither have cookie, the only remaining solution I see is adding hidden field with session id and transforming each link in form...

Comment: thanks for that suggestion. I guess I could change the route to accommodate the cookieless sesstionState but I don't really want the entire MVC app to be cookieless. Most of the mobile clients don't seem to have any issues with forms based authentication. Based on your idea I might try a custom authorization attribute using the session id...